# How do I suppress console messages in RPGLE generated by POST/GET?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have an RPGLE program that uses POST and GET using webservices (/QIBM/ProdData/OS/WebServices/V1/client/include/Axis.rpgleinc) and it works fine, except that when my program ends, it display the HTTP status, etc., with the "Press ENTER to end terminal session" message. I would like to prevent that from happening. I thought it would be a environment variable like QIBM_QSH_CMD_OUTPUT with QSH, but I can't find anything on it. I can make the POST/GET stuff to work, but in all likelihood, don't really know enough about it to ask this question correctly. Can anyone tell me what I need to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will get help if you post some code.